# Count the articles in a Paragraph

Tags: regex, perl

I need to count the articles (a , an, the) in a paragraph using perl. I try but it fails

```
$a += scalar(split(/a./, $_));
$an += scalar(split(/\san\s/, $_));
$the += scalar(split(/the/, $_));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex that `@npinti` suggested will work for you, but you need to use a global pattern match in list context and convert that to a scalar.

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = 'I need to count the articles (a , an, the) in a paragraph using perl.';

my @matches = $s =~ /\b(a|an|the)\b/g;
print scalar @matches, "\n";
```

**output**

```
5
```

Comment: From what I am getting, this *actually* counts the instances rather than just splitting.

Comment: Yes, it counts the number of instances of that regex pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like this: `\b(a|an|the)\b` (example [here](https://regex101.com/r/bP0kK4/1)). This can be broken down as:

- `\ba\b`   # look for the a article.
- `\ban\b`  # look for the an article.
- `\bthe\b` # look for the the article.

The problem with your regex is that with the exception of the `an` regex, you do not check to see if the article is a word within itself.

This first regex should match any `a` followed by any character, while the third will look for `the`, regardless of their location.

The `\b` will ensure that whatever you match, is either at the beginning of a string or else surrounded by white spaces.

Comment: @fahimfana: I am not a perl person, but did you try it like so: `scalar(split(/\ba\b/, $_));` for instance?

Comment: $a += scalar(split(/\ba\b/gi, $_));

Comment: @fahimfana: Maybe you need to enable the multi-line option? Please expand `getting some wrong`.

Comment: @npinti: Enabling multi-line applies only to `^` and `$`

Comment: The `split` solution isn't very nice as it counts the number of strings *between* the words, and so is one more than the count required unless the word appears at the end of the string.

Comment: @Borodin: I agree, if the word is in between other strings, then the result would be `count - 1`, otherwise, if it is at either edge of the string, this will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:^|(?<=\s))(?:a|an|the)(?=\s|$)
```

You can use this to count the articles.

Comment: Perhaps `(?<!\S)(?:a|an|the)(?!\S)`

Comment: No, `\S` matches *non-whitespace* and `b` and `a` aren't whitespace. However, it won't match `(a` or `an,` or `the)`, but neither does yours!

Comment: @Borodin aah didnt see the `negative` assertions.Yeah similar it is